# Formatting table code is not working in Macbook, it always show i haven't selected table

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

### My code is working in windows and its not working in the Mac machine
can anyone help me with the code error in this

Sub Singleheadertableformatting()
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim lngFont As Long
Dim objTable As Table
Dim oshp As Shape

```
On Error GoTo err1
Set objTable = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table
Set oshp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

For lngRow = 1 To 1
    For lngCol = 1 To 1
        If objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Selected Then
            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
                lngFont = .Size
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next

For lngRow = 1 To objTable.Rows.Count
    For lngCol = 1 To objTable.Columns.Count
        If objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Selected Then
            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
                .LineRuleWithin = msoTrue
                .SpaceWithin = 1
            End With

            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font
                .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With

            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
                .Size = lngFont
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Bold = False
                .Italic = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With

            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape
                .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Fill.Transparency = 0
            End With

            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape.TextFrame
                .MarginLeft = 6
                .MarginRight = 6
                .MarginTop = 3
                .MarginBottom = 3
                .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorTop
                .TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next

For lngRow = 1 To 1
    For lngCol = 1 To objTable.Columns.Count
        If objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Selected Then
            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape.TextFrame
                .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            End With

            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
                .Size = lngFont
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Bold = True
                .Italic = False
                .Color = RGB(134, 188, 37)
            End With

            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol)
                .Borders(ppBorderTop).Transparency = 0
                .Borders(ppBorderTop).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(134, 188, 37)
                .Borders(ppBorderTop).Weight = 3
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next

For lngRow = 1 To objTable.Rows.Count
    For lngCol = 1 To objTable.Columns.Count
        If objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).Selected Then
            With objTable.Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol)
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Transparency = 0
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Weight = 0.5
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Transparency = 0
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(187, 188, 188)
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Weight = 0.5
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next

MsgBox "Table Formatting Completed Successfully!", vbInformation
```

Normalexit:
Exit Sub

err1:
MsgBox "You haven't selected any table"
Resume Normalexit
End Sub

Comment: Your error handler will tell you that no table is selected no matter WHAT other error it encounters anywhere in your code. You should step through the code to see where the error actually occurs.